# Logging MAC addresses into a csv using scapy and python

Tags: python, csv, scapy

Alright, so I'm trying to create a csv file with a list of all mac addresses and SSIDs that have been seen. This is the code that I've got so far, most of it from: http://edwardkeeble.com/2014/02/passive-wifi-tracking/ I am using python 2.7.

```
from scapy.all import *
import csv, time
from datetime import datetime


PROBE_REQUEST_TYPE=0
PROBE_REQUEST_SUBTYPE=4

WHITELIST = ['de:ad:be:ef:ca:fe',] # Replace this with your phone's MAC address

def PacketHandler(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
        if pkt.type==PROBE_REQUEST_TYPE and pkt.subtype == PROBE_REQUEST_SUBTYPE and ( pkt.addr2.lower() not in WHITELIST and pkt.addr2.upper() not in WHITELIST):
            CheckCsv(pkt)

def PrintPacket(pkt):
    try:
        extra = pkt.notdecoded
    except:
        extra = None
    if extra!=None:
        signal_strength = -(256-ord(extra[-4:-3]))
    else:
        signal_strength = -100
        print "No signal strength found"
    print "Added: %s SSID: %s"%(pkt.addr2,pkt.getlayer(Dot11ProbeReq).info)

    with open('logmacs.csv','ab') as out:
        w=csv.writer(out)
        w.writerow([datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'),pkt.addr2,pkt.getlayer(Dot11ProbeReq).info,signal_strength])
        out.close()

def CheckCsv(pkt):
    with open('logmacs.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            if pkt.addr2 != row[2]:
                PrintPacket(pkt)
        f.close()


def main():
    print "[%s] Starting scan"%datetime.now()
    print "Scanning..."
    while True:
        sniff(iface=sys.argv[1],prn=PacketHandler, count=1)
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Right now it seems that either it captures a whole lot of packets or it gets stuck in a loop writing a single packet. I added the "count=1 and while True: and time.sleep(2)" to try to prevent that, but doesn't seem to have helped.

What I'm trying to do is log a date/time when a MAC is seen to create a list of unique MACs but this isn't quite doing that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't write to your output file while reading from it. Currently you update the contents of *logmacs.csv* in `PrintPacket` while iterating over it in `CheckCsv`.

I would modify `CheckCsv`'s implementation (and name) to store the monitored packets to some new variable in memory and to check whether the output file should be updated based on this newly introduced variable. This has the added advantage that it is also much more efficient.

I would also open the file for writing just once rather than in every single write (try using a `class` rather than a `function`).

---

**EDIT:**

In response to your request for clarification here is a basic implementation which is along the guidelines I was aiming for:

```
from scapy.all import *
from datetime import datetime
import csv

PROBE_REQUEST_TYPE = 0
PROBE_REQUEST_SUBTYPE = 4

WHITELIST = ['de:ad:be:ef:ca:fe',] # Replace this with your phone's MAC address

PACKET_FILE_PATH = 'logmacs.csv'

class PacketHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, packet_file_path):
        self.packet_file_path = packet_file_path
        self.handled_packets = set()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.csv_file = open(self.packet_file_path, 'ab')
        self.csv_writer = csv.writer(self.csv_file)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc_info):
        self.csv_file.close()

    def handle_packet(self, pkt):
        if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) and pkt.type == PROBE_REQUEST_TYPE and pkt.subtype == PROBE_REQUEST_SUBTYPE and (pkt.addr2.lower() not in WHITELIST and pkt.addr2.upper() not in WHITELIST) and pkt.addr2 not in self.handled_packets:
            self.add_packet(pkt)

    def add_packet(self, pkt):
        self.handled_packets.add(pkt.addr2)
        try:
            signal_strength = -(256 - ord(pkt.notdecoded[-4:-3]))
        except Exception, e:
            signal_strength = -100
            print "No signal strength found"
        self.csv_writer.writerow([datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                                  datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'),
                                  pkt.addr2,
                                  pkt.getlayer(Dot11ProbeReq).info,
                                  signal_strength])
        print "Added: %s SSID: %s" % (pkt.addr2, pkt.getlayer(Dot11ProbeReq).info)


def main():
    packet_handler = PacketHandler(PACKET_FILE_PATH)
    print "[%s] Starting scan" % datetime.now()
    print "Scanning..."
    with packet_handler as ph:
        sniff(iface=sys.argv[1], prn=ph.handle_packet)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The major improvements which I would like to highlight:

1. The output file is opened just once, during the `__enter__` method, which is invoked when the `with` statement is entered.
2. Rather than analyzing the output file in order to find out whether a certain client was already encountered, a local variable is maintained to hold all detected clients. Inspecting this variable is much more efficient then opening and reading the output file.

Comment: I got it working, I think. I have it read for the mac, then if it is found it sets a variable to true then breaks otherwise it continues checking. Then I have another if statement check the variable to decide if I need to add the mac because it doesn't already exist.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you still open the file twice on each packet, but have separated the two so they don't mix. That would solve the issue but is still less efficient than my proposal above (however, that might not be critical in your case). Anyway, as this answer solved your problem, please consider [up-voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173399) and [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) it. Note that there is absolutely no obligation to do any of these.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, I thought that's what I did. I can't figure out how to get code to show up properly... but if you could show me the code that would be a big help!

Here is what I've got so far: https://github.com/gaudard/scripts/blob/master/Python/MACAddrScanner.py

Comment: I've edited my answer and provided you with a sample implementation which you can build upon.